# Plot graph with php and jpgraph

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am trying to plot a realtime line graph by using php and jpgraph from a csv file. The .csv file is updated every 10 sec( every 10 sec will have one reord adding to it). I need to read the first 60 records or less to plot the first page. When it come to plot the second page. Which is the records from 61 to 120  records. But I need to skip the 1-60 records first. The following part of the code is what I use to read csv file:

```
$times = array();
$values1 = array(); 
$values2 = array();
$values3 = array();
$values4 = array();

//$i=1;
//$j=1;

$file_lines = file($DispFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


foreach( $file_lines as $line_num => $line_value) {
  fixIndex();
  if ($line_num < $i)continue;  // skip records in 60* range
  $line_elements = explode(",", $line_value);
  $times[] = date("H:i:s", $line_elements[0]);
  $values1[] = $line_elements[1];
  $values2[] = $line_elements[2];
  $values3[] = $line_elements[3];
  $values4[] = $line_elements[4];
}

// set the starting point in multiple of 60
function fixIndex() {
  $i=1;
  $j=1;
  global $i, $j;
  $a=$j-$i;
  if ($a === 5){
    $i+=5;
  }
  $j++;
}
```

the `$i` in `if ($line_num < $i)continue;` doesn't seem to be able to change from 1, to 61, 121, and so on. the program still can run without any error message. Can any one help to make that `$i work`? or using other method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're setting i as 1